# MaxDetect speed

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, image-processing, mathematical-optimization

What's the fastest way to find the local maxima of a 2D list?  *E.g.*

```
nx = ny = 100;
dat = Table[Sin[2. \[Pi] x/nx] (0.1 + Cos[2. \[Pi] y/ny]), {y, 0, ny}, {x, 0, nx}];

ListPlot3D[dat]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This (updated) function has three local maxima of different heights:

```
Position[MaxDetect[dat], 1]
(* {{1, 26}, {51, 76}, {101, 26}} *)

dat[[1, 26]]
dat[[51, 76]]
dat[[101, 26]]
(* 1.1, 0.9, 1.1 *)
```

My original attempt was super-slow:

```
RepeatedTiming[MaxDetect[Chop@dat];][[1]]
(* 1.55 *)
```

Turns out using `Chop` is a very bad idea.  Without it is 100X faster:

```
RepeatedTiming[MaxDetect[dat];][[1]]
(* 0.016 *)
```

Along the way I discovered another version that is 2X faster yet:

```
RepeatedTiming[MaxDetect[Image[dat]];][[1]]
(* 0.0067 *)
```

**Questions**

1. Why is `MaxDetect` so much slower when `Chop` is applied? (I should add that my actual non-example problem has lots of small values that needed to `Chop`-ping)
2. Why does converting to an `Image` speed it up further?
3. Is there any faster way available?

Comment: how about `UnitStep[dat - Max[dat]]`?

Comment: also `Chop[dat, Max@dat]`

Comment: I see now that my toy example was too simplistic.  In my real problem, not all local maxima are equal, so this approach doesn't work.  Let me adjust the question.  Sorry!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Why is `MaxDetect` so much slower when `Chop` is applied?

Because `Chop` returns exact zeros what prevents packing of the matrix attempted by `MaxDetect`. You can detect an attempt to pack the array with `Trace`:

```
Trace[MaxDetect[{{1.}}], Developer`ToPackedArray] // Flatten
```

[image: screenshot]

Applying `N` after `Chop` gives almost the same speed as without `Chop` because now the matrix can be packed again:

```
RepeatedTiming[MaxDetect[dat];][[1]]
RepeatedTiming[MaxDetect[N@Chop@dat];][[1]]
```

> ```
> 0.06
> 0.07
> ```

---

> Why does converting to an `Image` speed it up further?

It seems that `MaxDetect` is simply not so well-optimized for an array input as compared to an `Image` input. A superficial analysis follows.

1. Compare the complexity of `Trace` outputs in the both cases:

   ```
   Trace[MaxDetect[dat]] // LeafCount
   Trace[MaxDetect[Image@dat]] // LeafCount
   ```

   > ```
   > 79670996
   > 260610
   > ```

   It indicates that in the case of array input it is evaluated many times as an (unpacked?) array, while in the case of `Image` input it is evaluated as an atomic `Image` object what may be faster.
2. Additional evidences in support of the previous guess:

   ```
   Count[Trace[MaxDetect[dat]], _Image, Infinity]
   Count[Trace[MaxDetect[Image@dat]], _Image, Infinity]
   ```

   > ```
   > 8
   > 1913
   > ```

   ```
   Count[Trace[MaxDetect[dat]], _List?MatrixQ, Infinity]
   Count[Trace[MaxDetect[Image@dat]], _List?MatrixQ, Infinity] // Quiet
   ```

   > ```
   > 7432
   > 367
   > ```
3. And finally let us compare how many packed and non-packed array evaluations appear in the both cases:

   ```
   Count[Trace[MaxDetect[dat]], a_List /; Developer`PackedArrayQ[a], Infinity]
   Count[Trace[MaxDetect[Image@dat]], a_List /; Developer`PackedArrayQ[a], Infinity] // Quiet
   ```

   > ```
   > 102
   > 204
   > ```

   ```
   Count[Trace[MaxDetect[dat]], a_List /; ! Developer`PackedArrayQ[a], Infinity]
   Count[Trace[MaxDetect[Image@dat]], a_List /; ! Developer`PackedArrayQ[a], Infinity] // Quiet
   ```

   > ```
   > 748562
   > 8706
   > ```

   From the last output we see that there seems to be about 100 times more evaluations of non-packed arrays in the case of array input as compared to `Image` input. I think that now the situation is clear enough.

Comment: A better alternative to `N`+`Chop` would be `Threshold`. That keeps the arrays packed all the time.

Answer (score 10):

> Is there any faster way available?

There is, if you're willing to to use a different definition of "local maximum". If a local maximum is any value at least as high as any value in a 11x11 neighborhood, then you can use `UnitStep[dat - Dilation[dat, 5]]`, which is about 16 times faster for your data:

```
RepeatedTiming[MaxDetect[dat];][[1]]
```

> 0.016

```
RepeatedTiming[UnitStep[dat - Dilation[dat, 5]];][[1]]
```

> 0.00101

But the result is slightly different:

[image]

Note the marked pixels on the left border in the `dat-Dilation` version. By the definition above, these pixels mark one extended local maximum.

Comment: Conversion to 64-bit floating point numbers doesn't increase the speed significantly: try `RepeatedTiming[MaxDetect[Image[dat, "Real64"]];][[1]]`.

Answer (score 8):

A severe problem is that `Table` generates an unpacked array, a thing that is often very annoying. When converting to an image, it is packed automatically (one can check that, e.g., with `` Developer`PackedArrayQ[ImageData[Image[dat]]] ``). And because many functions work faster on packed arrays than on unpacked ones, this increases the performance.

A vectorized implementation that exploits the very nature of the function (and is thus not very generalizable) is the following:

```
nx = ny = 1000;
dat = KroneckerProduct[
     (0.1 + Cos[Subdivide[0., 2. Pi, ny]]),
     Sin[Subdivide[0., 2. Pi, nx]]
     ];
```

> 0.003691

The maxima can be found by comparing each value to the maximum of its neighbors. The latter can be done efficiently with `MaxFilter`:

```
getindex = {Quotient[#, Dimensions[dat][[1]]] + 1, Mod[#, Dimensions[dat][[2]], 1]} &;
idx = getindex /@ 
     Random`Private`PositionsOf[
      Flatten@UnitStep[dat - MaxFilter[dat, {1, 1}]], 
      1
      ]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
idx
MatrixPlot@SparseArray[idx -> 1, Dimensions[dat]]
```

> 0.00108
>
> {{1, 26}, {29, 1}, {30, 1}, {31, 1}, {32, 1}, {33, 1}, {34, 1}, {35, 
>     1}, {36, 1}, {37, 1}, {38, 1}, {39, 1}, {40, 1}, {41, 1}, {42, 
>     1}, {43, 1}, {44, 1}, {45, 1}, {46, 1}, {47, 1}, {48, 1}, {49, 
>     1}, {50, 1}, {51, 1}, {51, 76}, {52, 1}, {53, 1}, {54, 1}, {55, 
>     1}, {56, 1}, {57, 1}, {58, 1}, {59, 1}, {60, 1}, {61, 1}, {62, 
>     1}, {63, 1}, {64, 1}, {65, 1}, {66, 1}, {67, 1}, {68, 1}, {69, 
>     1}, {70, 1}, {71, 1}, {72, 1}, {73, 1}, {101, 26}}

[image]

This is about 10 times faster than `MaxDetect`. But it does not distinguish between local maxima and strict local maxima. However, a second sweep over the local maxima (which is much less expensive) could filter out the strict local maxima.

Comment: The OP has [changed](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/206636/maxdetect-speed/206643#comment531401_206636) the problem in a breaking way in his last edit, so the solutions by kglr and Ulrich are no more acceptable: he states that the function may have several local maxima with different heights. I do not know how best to behave in this situation: such a change is against the rules of the site (as I understand).

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Oh my, you are right. Well, I changed my answer towards the new question.

Answer (score 6):

A little bit faster than @kglr 's tricky answer is

```
Position[dat, Max[dat]]
```